# Why wont the variable be passed to PHP using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm a beginner at using AJAX and PHP . What I'm trying to do is send a ID to a JavaScript function as soon as the user clicks on a anchor tag that's in a echo below. I'm trying to get a variable from chargers-cables.php and use it in selected-product.php but it seems that the variable is empty when it gets there.

chargers-cables.php

```
<script>
    function saveSession(ccID) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/selected-product.php",
            data: {ID: ccID },
            success: alert("SUCCESS !")
        });

        console.log("ID = " + ccID);
            window.location.href = "selected-product.php";
        }
</script>

echo " <div> <a onclick= \"saveSession($ccID)\" > <img src= " . $imageURL . "> </a>  <a class=\"product\" href=\"selected-product.php\"> " . $productName . "</a>  </div> ";
```

selected-product.php

```
if(empty($_POST["ID"])){
    echo "Error";
}else{
    $cc_ID = $_POST["ID"];           
}
    echo("<script>console.log('PHP: " . $cc_ID . "');</script>");
    // $cc_ID is empty !
```

Comment: `window.location.href` is GET method not POST

Comment: @AntonyJack is correct. You're redirecting the page. Try using e.preventDefaut(). Also  $ccID isn't defined in your example.

Comment: try to change location only after request finnish

$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/selected-product.php",
   data: {ID: ccID },
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   window.location.href = "selected-product.php";
  });

Answer (score 1):

You're sending the value to a PHP page. The server creates a page from the script and sends it to the client. Then, you're redirecting. This creates a new request on the server, which generates an entirely new page with new variables and sends that to the client. Your variable is lost unless you save it in a session variable. Even if you do, the asynchronous nature of AJAX is likely to make this unreliable.

If you want to pass a variable this way, just add it to the URL:

```
<script>
        function saveSession(ccID) {

            console.log("ID = " + ccID);
            window.location.href = "selected-product.php?ID="+ccID;
        }

    </script>

 echo " <div> <a onclick= \"saveSession($ccID)\" > <img src= " . $imageURL . "> </a>  <a class=\"product\" href=\"selected-product.php\"> " . $productName . "</a>  </div> ";
```

Then:

```
if(empty($_GET["ID"]))   // GET here instead of POST
{
    echo "Error";

}
else{
        $cc_ID = $_GET["ID"];
        
}

echo("<script>console.log('PHP: " . $cc_ID . "');</script>");
// $cc_ID is empty !
```

If you're trying to do this with AJAX to avoid a page reload then your JavaScript needs to handle the response from the server and draw a new page with the data it has sent. That's a different problem.